# Is there a way to restrict node.js to ONLY look into node_modules folder in a particular directory when executing?

Tags: node.js

I have a folder structure like this:

- root/
- root/node_modules/
- root/file1.js
- root/folder1/
- root/folder1/file2.js
- root/folder1/node_modules/

file1.js and file2.js requires same package X but with different versions. (file1 needs X@1.0 and file2 needs X@2.0). The packages also share multiple sub-packages with same names.

file1.js internally calls file2.js. When doing so, file1.js uses the root/node_modules/ and causes error because file2.js needs to use root/folder1/node_modules/.

When executing file2.js from inside folder1 using cli, it works well.

Is there a way to restrict the code to use only particular "node_module" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make `file2.js` look into its own `node_modules` folder.

In `file2.js`, instead of module requirement that usually does, you can specify the target `node_modules`:

```
// file2.js
const X = require('./node_modules/X');
```